# Error report on FBSDKLoginButton

Tags: error-handling, crash-reports, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I have the following error and I have no idea where it's coming from.
I really need help.
Thank you.[Click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKt17.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 
If like me you encounter this type of problem it could be due to a language change in your settings (localization) or your main storyboard.
What I did is I put back everything to default, did a Product > Clean, and deleted the app and reinstalled it.